# Using haml for post files with middleman blog

Tags: haml, middleman

I have a Middleman blog with post files in source/journal.

My blog config:

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  # set options on blog
  blog.prefix = "journal"
  blog.permalink = "{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html.haml"
  blog.sources = "{title}.html.haml"
  blog.layout = "journal_layout"
end
```

And a post file in source/journal/2015-12-02-hello-world.html.haml

```
\---
title: Hello World
date: 2015-12-02
category: Photography
\---

%article
  %h1 Hello World
  %p Denver, Colorado :: December 2nd, 2015
  %p Lore ipsum dolar
```

I can pull up the page with a direct url but the post doesn't register with:

```
- blog.articles[0...5].each do |article|
  %article
    %h2= link_to article.title, article.url
```

...and the frontmatter just appears as plain text at the top of the page.

Many thanks for your time.

UPDATE!

blog config should be:

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  # set options on blog
  blog.prefix = "journal"
  blog.permalink = "{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  blog.sources = "{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html.haml"
  blog.layout = "journal_layout"
end
```

and the article HAML file:

```
---
title: Hello World
date: 2015-12-02
category: Photography
---

%article
  %h1 Hello World
  %p Denver, Colorado :: December 2nd, 2015
  %p Lore ipsum dolar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are including the full file extension ".html.haml" but what the middleman blog extension is expecting is the final (processed) file extension which is simply ".html".

Change your blog configuration to the following and it should work:

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  # set options on blog
  blog.prefix = "journal"
  blog.permalink = "{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  blog.sources = "{title}.html"
  blog.layout = "journal_layout"
end
```